# Inserting background image using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, image, path

I am setting the background for an element using

`background: url("../img/mapfield-icon.png");`

I am trying to switch the element using jquery when an event happens. This is the code I am using.

`$('#zipCodeBtn').css({ background: 'url("../img/mapfield-icon_yellow.png")'});`

When it looks for the file though, it doesnt find it. This is what comes up in Inspect Element

`background: url(file:///img/mapfield-icon_yellow.png);`

Comment: You need to make sure that the image url is correct. your project should be in webapps folder if you are deploying it on tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

First you forgot the quotes on 'background'. 
Second you don't have to use .css() with a hash inside.

You can do something like:

```
$('#zipCodeBtn').css('background-image', 'url("../img/mapfield-icon_yellow.png")');
```

Another possibility is to make 2 classes:

```
.normal-icon { background: url("../img/mapfield-icon.png"); }
.yellow-icon { background: url("../img/mapfield-icon_yellow.png"); }
```

And the JS:

```
$('zipCodeBtn').removeClass('.normal-icon').addClass('.yellow-icon');
```